# Database datatype Conversion Issue

Tags: c#

I am fetching data from sql server and exporting it to excel programmatically using c#.Based on the column data type, I am doing format of cell.Here I am facing one issue.

In sql server,retrieving column data type is defined as numeric(20,0).In my application column type is coming as Decimal.I want to get the type other numeric type like Double or Int64. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How are you getting the data from the DB? Are you using a DateReader, DataAdapter, or some other ORM? The safest way is probably to keep getting it as a `decimal` and then convert it in C# so you can deal with any overflow conditions..

Answer (score 0):

Since the datatype in the DB is numeric, you have two options to get either a double or int.

1. Change the datatype in the database from numeric to int.
2. Receive the data as a decimal and round it. For this, use Math.Round as Convert.ToInt32 can have some unexpected behavior.